# Linked List: Inserting a node at the end

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I've been learning Data Structures and currently working with Linked List. I'm trying to add a node at the end of the linked list but not able to figure out the correct logic for it. I've tried inserting a node at the beginning and it works fine.

This is the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node* next;
};

Node* head; // global
void Insert(int data) {
    Node* temp = new Node();
    temp -> data = data;
    temp -> next = head;
    head = temp;
} // insert an integer

void Print(){
    Node* temp = head;
    cout << "List is: ";
    while (temp != NULL) {
        cout << temp -> data << " ";
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    cout << endl;
} // print all elements in the list

void Delete(int n){
    Node* temp1 = head;
    if(n == 1) {
        head = temp1 -> next; // head now points to second node
        delete temp1;
        return;
    }
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n-2; i++)
        temp1 = temp1 -> next;
        // temp1 points to (n-1)th Node
    Node* temp2 = temp1 -> next; // nth Node
    temp1 -> next = temp2 -> next; // (n+1)th Node
    delete temp2; // delete temp2
} // Delete node at position n

int main() {
    head = NULL; // empty list
    Insert(2);
    Insert(4);
    Insert(6);
    Insert(5); // List: 2,4,6,5
    Print();
    int n;
    cout << "Enter a postion: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    Delete(n);
    Print();
}
```

This code deletes a node at nth position. The node here is being adding from the beginning and I'm trying to figure out the logic to insert it from the end.

Any suggestions and advises on this will be very helpful.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Try writing a function that returns a pointer to the last node. When you have that working perfectly, return to the question of how to add a node to the end of the list.

Comment: Some other unrelated hints: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. If you like my answer, please mark the question as resolved by clicking the checkmark in my answer. Also, I added a link to an online IDE so you can try out the function yourself.

Comment: If you include a `tail` pointer, you can add at the end in 0(1) time without iteration. [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) see the `add` function. (C -- but the logic is the same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Play with the code.](https://godbolt.org/z/WfKE6K)

```
void insert_end(int data) {
    Node* temp = new Node();  // 1
    temp->data = data;
    temp -> next = nullptr;
    
    Node* n = head;
    if (!n) {         // 2
        head = temp;
        return;
    }
    while(n->next) {  // 3
        n = n->next;
    }
    n->next = temp;
}
```

**Short explanation of the method:**

`1:` You create a new `Node` and set the data.

`2:` Check if the list is empty. If it is, insert the new element at the head.

`3:` If the list is not empty, you read the next element of the list until you have the last Node in your list. If you would write `while(n)...` here, you would get to the end of the list, meaning a `nullptr` and the code would break.

Comment: After making changes and adding this function, I'm trying to print it but it's not able to show any output in console

Comment: Click on `Play with code`. The implementation there prints the entire list, including the newly added elements

Comment: @User12547645 you should test for `head` being `nullptr` or will have a crash.